# components of mixed tensor with same indices

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

If my tensor $a^{\mu\nu}=$ matrix of 4*4 size (let's say, in 1+3 dimensions with mostly negative convention for the metric), what is $a^{\mu}_{\mu}$ ? Is it the trace or the vector of diagonal elements or the matrix containing only diagonal elements as the non-zero elements ?

Comment: Assuming Einstein summation notation? $a^{\mu}_{\mu}=a^1_1+a^2_2 + \cdots$

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit confused because when we write $a^{\mu\mu}$, we are able to write the matrix elements also as $a^{11}$ and so on. But in case of $a_{\mu}^{\mu}$, it is the sum if we take Einstein's convention. Okay, now, I am wondering what is $a^{\mu\mu}$ ? Is it the matrix with only diagonal elements as non-zero or just the vector of diagonal elements ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general convention is that all repeated ("dummy") indices (and they had better only be repeated in pairs, one up, one down) are summed over. All remaining indices -- the "free" indices -- vary over all possible values.

- With no free indices, you have a rank-0 tensor (a scalar).
- With one free index, you have a rank-1 tensor (a vector), which can be written as a column or a row.
- With two free indices, you have a rank-2 tensor, which can always be written as a matrix.

So $a^{\mu\nu}$ is representable as a matrix not simply because it has two indices, but because it has two *free* indices. On the other hand, $a^\mu_\mu$ has no free indices and so must be a scalar. In particular, it is the trace of the rank-2 tensor $a$.

By the way, only symmetric tensors can unambiguously use overstacked indices in general. That is, unless $a^{\mu\nu} = a^{\nu\mu}$, you don't know whether $a^\mu_\nu$ refers to ${a^\mu}_\nu \equiv g_{\nu\lambda} a^{\mu\lambda}$ or ${a_\nu}^\mu \equiv g_{\nu\lambda} a^{\lambda\mu}$. In the special case of taking the trace it turns out not to matter, since
$$ {a^\mu}_\mu \equiv g_{\mu\lambda} a^{\mu\lambda} \stackrel{\text{symmetry of $g$}}{\equiv} g_{\lambda\mu} a^{\mu\lambda} \equiv {a_\lambda}^\lambda \equiv {a_\mu}^\mu $$
always, but it's nonetheless rare to see $a^\mu_\mu$ written.

To summarize, $a^{\mu\nu}$, $a_{\mu\nu}$, ${a^\mu}_\nu$, and ${a_\mu}^\nu$ are all representable by (generally different) $4\times4$ matrices, while ${a^\mu}_\mu \equiv {a_\mu}^\mu \equiv a^\mu_\mu$ is simply a scalar, equal to the the trace of the matrices that represent ${a^\mu}_\nu$ or ${a_\mu}^\nu$ (these two matrices would be transposes of one another in any consistent way of assigning indices to rows/columns, and so have the same trace).

Comment: Chris, thanks for the nice answer. Actually, I wrote it that way because I didn't know how to write it the other way and I realized that it won't matter because of what you have mentioned in the answer already. Just to be more clear, can you tell me what is $a^{\nu\nu}$ - should it be the matrix with only diagonal elements as non-zero or just the vector of diagonal elements ? because I ain't even contracting the index but restricting them to be same.

Comment: Repeated generic indices ($\mu$ or $i$ as opposed to $3$ or $y$) not meant to be summed over are a bit dangerous, but assuming no mistake is made I would interpret them the same as non-generic indices, just unspecified. So $a^{\nu\nu}$ would be a single, unspecified diagonal component of a rank-2 tensor, just like $a^{33}$ would be a single, specified component.

Comment: Does this also mean that $a^{\nu\nu}$ standalone is not a tensor?